# Connect to the db each time with a different user

Tags: mysql, privileges

I'm trying to increment the security of my website implementing the best security systems I can. I know that it's good to create different users with different privileges, but would be useful creating one user per each function?

I explain it better: I created different functions for the different actions like `dbSelect()`, `dbInsert()` and `dbUpdate()`. Would increase the security of the system make that each function connects to a MySQL user who has *only* the `SELECT` privilege, in case of dbSelect(), the `INSERT` privilege, in case of dbInsert(), etc?

In a page, of course, there could be all of the three functions, so does connecting to the db for a SELECT, then closing the connection to open the INSERT one, then again the SELECT, etc. affect the db in terms of performance?

Comment: Jones is correct. If you really think about it, one user that can select from any table doesn't help security much. Hackers typically just want to select all your data so they can use it for profit. Updating or deleting your data doesn't really do anything for the hacker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This question will probably get closed, because it's a matter of opinion. But, I have an opinion.)

It is a good idea for a complex application to use several different db users.

But it doesn't makes sense to do what you suggest: to have one database user to do SELECT, and another to do INSERT, etc, if only because those two queries can be combined in practice.

What does make sense?

To have three user roles:

1. call it "webapp", gets used for routine day to day operations on behalf of your web app's users. It should probably be able to select / insert / update and maybe delete rows from operational tables.
2. call it "webadmin", gets used by your web app for such things as adding and deleting users.  This user will have insert / update  and maybe delete privs on the more slowly changing tables, like users. It's used much more rarely than the first account.
3. call it "dba" or something, never gets used by the web app itself. It's used by the person logging in to make changes to your database. It has all privs, including creating, truncating, and dropping tables, indexes, procedures. You *never* put the password for the "dba" account into your web app's code or configuration files.

You might have two other accounts:

4. "billing" would be used only by the billing portion of your web app, and would have access to tables containing any user billing information you keep.
5. "reports" would work kind of like "dba". It would be able to read almost all tables (maybe not the billing tables) but not insert / update / delete.

The trick is this: get most of your web app working with the least privileged "webapp" account, and only use the elevated privilege accounts when you need them.

Comment: As I was thinking, then, my idea is useless; but I like your 4th and 5th point 'cause I never thought about it!